# How to fix a "value too long for type character varying(255)" error

Tags: ruby, sinatra, carrierwave, datamapper

I'm trying to save a file so that I can upload it to stripe using CarrierWave, but I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)
```

and don't understand why as I followed the CarrierWave usage guide on GitHub.

This is my application:

```
class SplitterStripeServer < Sinatra::Base

  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.root = File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/public"
  end

  post "/" do
    img = Image.new
    img.file = params[:file] #carrierwave will upload the file automatically
    img.save!
    redirect to("/")
  end

  get "/upload" do
    erb :upload
  end

  get "/" do
    @image = Image.find(1)
    erb :index
  end
end
```

This is the uploader:

```
class ImagesUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :file
end
```

This is the model:

```
class Image
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  mount_uploader :file, ImagesUploader
end
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Would help if you put the line number in which the error is occurring.

Comment: sorry, its occuring when i call `image.save`

Comment: Please take the time to use proper grammar. Punctuation and spelling do matter on Stack Overflow, which is an online reference book, not a discussion list.

Comment: @the Tin Man done, apologies, any clues on a solution though?

Comment: You're sending too much data for a string field in the database. The field only allows 255 characters.

Comment: I understand that part but im sending a file by carrierwave to be stored so why am i getting this error. I thought this was the whole point of carrierwave?

Comment: @Wazza how did you fix?

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrease a length of a file name. Override `filename` method and cut a file's basename e.g. to 250 characters.

```
class ImagesUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :file

  def filename
     "#{file.basename[0..250]}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end
end
```

Comment: Im still getting the same error when I do this but it made me think I should pass `params[:file][:tempfile]` This gives me a different error but its now saying that when I call `image.id` after `image = Image.find(1)` that id is an undefined method?

Comment: Try to check filename before upload `img=Image.new(file: params[:file]); img.file.filename`.

Comment: when i do `p params[:file][:filename]` i get "17.jpg"

Comment: if i `p params[:file]` i get `{:filename=>"17.jpg", :type=>"image/jpeg", :name=>"file", :tempfile=>#<Tempfile:/var/folders/tz/7fkzt6m112l4hb54xjp14z800000gq/T/RackMultipart20170113-35991-dn0pqk.jpg>, :head=>"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"17.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"}` so i can see tempfile is why im getting the error but i dont know what to do from there

Answer (score 0):

check if you have additional installed gems
I had was installed gem `validates_lengths_from_database` and this gem doesn't understand how to work with carrierwave. I am just turn off it in model `validates_lengths_from_database except: %i[file]`