# value too long for type character varying(255) - carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am using rails 5.2.4, ruby 2.6.6 and carrierwave 2.0. When I try to save image, I get an error `value too long for type character varying(255)` because my field is string(I made it by docs).

After I made attr_accessor :image, I can save image, but cannot get it. I think will help :text instead of :string, but I want to know why does not work with string. Help me, please.

P.S.
I know about [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642491/how-to-fix-a-value-too-long-for-type-character-varying255-error), but there is not answer.

model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w[jpg jpeg png]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

it was problem with gem `validates_lengths_from_database`. I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65970347/6532309)